# Inline comment behavior in python 3.6 different from 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

So I am moving my code from python 2.7 to 3.6 (yay!). However, I realized that all my super-long config files will need to be modified because while a line like this was valid in a config file in 2.7, it is not in 3.6

```
SCALE_PRECIPITATION = 1000.0 ; Convert from m to mm
```

Is there a way to have inline comment in a config file in python 3.6?

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    from configparser import ConfigParser as SafeConfigParser
else:
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser(inline_comment_prefixes=True)
parser.read('config_file.txt')
```

Comment: What are you using to parse these config files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can specify `inline_comment_prefixes` as an argument to [`configparser.ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser).

> When inline_comment_prefixes is given, it will be used as the set of substrings that prefix comments in non-empty lines.

This behavior was changed in python3.2:

> Changed in version 3.2: In previous versions of `configparser` behaviour matched `comment_prefixes=('#',';')` and `inline_comment_prefixes=(';',)`.

Note that this also tells you what values to use to recover the old behavior ;-).

Comment: @wim -- I was just adding that :-).